# swappiness doesnt work correctly in ubuntu 23.10

Tags: swap, 23.10

ubuntu 23.10 swapps like crazy - atm i am at the half of my ram used and my swap is already 1gb.
it goes to crazier values like 3-4 gbs in the swap.
it was working way better in the previous ubuntu's.

since few past releases i have vm.swappiness = 1 set in the sysctl.conf
but 23.10 seems to ignore it
what changed?
is it a bug? does anybod has any idea how to get it to work?

also please dont tell me that it supposed to work like that and its correct that it swaps... i am a programist and i have many 'memory usage peaks' due to many tools that i use and it slows down my system - and doing swapoff / swapon frequently is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Swap memory that is stored in the hard drive is slow. Use ZRAM instead.

First, remove the swapfile/swap partition in `/etc/fstab`. Then, configure ZRAM.

```
git clone https://github.com/foundObjects/zram-swap.git
cd zram-swap && sudo ./install.sh
```

Afterwards, reboot.

Comment: it doesnt solve the issue that ubuntu swaps like crazy now. packing(ziping) the swap is another thing...